# Semantic-ui-react Dimmer warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, strict-mode

When I use Dimmer from semantic-ui-react I got this warrning:

*Warning: `findDOMNode` is deprecated in StrictMode. `findDOMNode` was passed an instance of RefFindNode which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node*

But as I see the problem with Dimmer was resolved years before: [link](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2732).

So what's the root of warring and how to avoid it (except of stop using strict mode)?

```
import React from "react";
import { Dimmer } from "semantic-ui-react";

const App = () => (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Dimmer>Hey</Dimmer>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

export default App;
```

React 18.2.0, Semantic-ui-react 2.1.4, [Link to codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/dimmer-in-strictmode-react-18-2-0-ip43e9)

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this ?

Comment: @PatrickHume, no. Live with a warring...  (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a late reply but if you use v3-beta (https://react.semantic-ui.com/migration-guide), it supports native ref forwarding.

```
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.5.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
```

Hope this helps ;)